# preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated error

Tags: php

I am currently looking to fix a small section of NagiosQL that is giving me some depreciation errors, mainly

```
Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback       instead in /srv/nagiosql/public_html/libraries/pear/HTML/Template/IT.php on line 1095
```

The block on line 1095 is

```
        return preg_replace(
        "#<!-- INCLUDE (.*) -->#ime",
        "\$this->getFile('\\1')",
        $content
    );
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do what the error says... Use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback).

Answer (score 5):

Use **preg_replace_callback**

```
return preg_replace_callback(
    "#<!-- INCLUDE (.*) -->#im",
    array($this, 'getFile'),
    $content
);
```